# ICMP/Internet checksum if packet entirely constists of zeros

Tags: icmp, checksum

We are currently investigating a strange behavior of different devices: if we send "empty" ICMP packets (that is, ICMP-SEQ and ICMP-ID are 0x0000 and no ICMP payload), for example using

```
nping --icmp --icmp-seq=0 --icmp-id=0 8.8.8.8
```

then different systems reply differently:

- an Asus router, Windows 7 PC, Fritz!Box, Kali Linux box, all reply with checksum **0xFFFF**, which is correct according to wireshark
- However, 8.8.8.8 and heise.de (193.99.144.80) both reply with **0x0000**, which is marked as wrong by wireshark.

I am pretty sure that I have also seen 0xFFFF from 8.8.8.8, but I currently can't reproduce this.

**SO, my Questions:**

- What's the correct Internet Checksum for a packet consisting only of Zeros
- Is this behavior different if the packed is relayed via NAT (i.e. relayed through our router)?

Note: This ICMP packet is valid according to RFC 792

PS: I hope serverfault is the correct forum to ask. If not, I apologize in advance ;)

Comment: I can confirm this issue is still alive and well in 2018, the output on my mac shows invalid checksum responses from google.com with the OP's same command. `wrong icmp cksum 0 (->ffff)!`. I think this comes down to how the checksum is calculated on the remote host versus the machine that sent the request.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around with `tcpdump`, `nping` and `nmap` for about three hours, I've managed to determine the following:
Windows calculates the checksum properly, and basically nobody else does.
When you have a packet that's all 0's, you should get a checksum of 0xffff ([source](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1071)), but every linux/BSD machine I've pinged has returned a checksum of 0x0000. I think this just comes down to an error in how the checksum is being calculated on many servers.

Comment: I'm not putting this in my answer because I'm not sure about it, but I think the reason *nix reports the sum incorrectly is because a number of exploits have historically used checksum manipulation with icmp requests having an id of 0.